# Finding the key of encrypted string (given known decrypted message)

Tags: encryption

I have a bunch of messages where I can run the encrypted message against a validation services, and get a response that the encrypted message is valid as well as the contents of the encrypted message.
Naturally, I dont know the encryption key.

Is it possible to find out the key in order to compose a encrypted message?

Comment: Not if it's a well implemented modern encryption algorithm. It's one of the properties they defend against

Comment: @Matthew, add that as an answer if you are willing to elaborate a little bit.